# Double quote in php json encode

Tags: php, json

The JSON out of my file is:

```
[{"name":"ltrs","data":["25","80","110","113","139","1025","1026","1027","1028","1029"]},{"name":"total","data":["3","723","19","48","3","6","14","17","15","6"]}]
```

I require:

```
[{"name":"ltrs","data":["25","80","110","113","139","1025","1026","1027","1028","1029"]},{"name":"total","data":[3,723,19,48,3,6,14,17,15,6}]
```

JSON required for plotting bar chart in `highchart.js`.

When I run php query from mysql for json encode it gives the output with double quote.

Comment: Without the underlying code generating that JSON we really can't help you

Comment: is there any difference in the above two? i don't think so. they are identical.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh notice the absence of double-quotes around the integers at the end. that or the slider not being the same length.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do this if `name = total`

Here is the code try it:

```
var a = [{"name":"ltrs","data":["25","80","110","113","139","1025","1026","1027","1028","1029"]},{"name":"total","data":["3","723","19","48","3","6","14","17","15","6"]}];


$.each(a, function(k,v){

if(v.name == 'total'){
  $.each(v.data, function(k1,v1){
      v.data[k1] = v1*1;;
  });
}
});
console.log(a);
```

Comment: If you want to do this for all data values then just remove "if" condition